# Arranging photos by date taken in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

I am trying to upload a scanned image to the new Google Photos app (Windows Desktop). For some reason changing the exif info to 1982 still puts the photo as uploaded today. So my photo collection is not sorted by date taken. Is this fixable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I've read is to download Windows Photo Gallery and modify the date in that.  I did that, and I can see the date in the pic has changed, but still shows up with the old date.  Wondering if once the date is changed, a re-scan is needed.